# creating a temporary table from the results of a "with query"

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a data pipeline that pulls a bunch of data from Postgres and pushes it into a data display tool.  My typical flow looks like this, and it works fine:

```
create temporary table foo as 
select w.id, w.name, w.created_at
from waldo w;
\copy "foo" to './foo.txt';
```

I then use that dumped-out foo.txt file.  (The actual query is a lot more complex and does joins and group-bys on a dozen other tables, but you get the idea.)

I've developed a query that uses a "with query" and I can't figure out the syntax to get the result into a text file.  This query runs fine in my interactive SQL window:

```
WITH daze 
     AS (SELECT ( CURRENT_DATE - b.offs ) AS date 
         FROM   (SELECT Generate_series(0, CURRENT_DATE - '2015-01-15', 1) AS 
                        offs) 
                AS b) 
select w.id, w.name, w.created_at               
from waldo w, daze d
where d.date + 1 > w.created_at
```

But I need to get that into my daily dump script, and get a temporary table object that I can dump out.  And this code doesn't run:

```
create temporary table foo as 
WITH daze 
     AS (SELECT ( CURRENT_DATE - b.offs ) AS date 
         FROM   (SELECT Generate_series(0, CURRENT_DATE - '2015-01-15', 1) AS 
                        offs) 
                AS b) 
select w.id, w.name, w.created_at               
from waldo w, daze d
where d.date + 1 > w.created_at
```

What's the syntax I'm struggling for?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*doesn't run*" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Comment: I can't spot your version of Postgres. And why do you need a temp table? You can `\copy` from a query directly.

Comment: Your statement runs just fine for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4d634/1 (can't use `temporary` in SQLFiddle, but that shouldn't make a difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole CTE is a very convoluted way of doing:

```
generate_series(CURRENT_DATE::timestamp, '2015-01-15'::timestamp, interval '-1 day') AS date
```

So why not simply:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS 
  SELECT w.id, w.name, w.created_at               
  FROM waldo w,
       generate_series((CURRENT_DATE + 1)::timestamp, '2015-01-16'::timestamp, interval '-1 day') AS d(date)
  WHERE d.date > w.created_at;
```

(Note that the `+ 1` from the `WHERE` clause is absorbed in the `generate_series()` call.)

Comment: Thank you. The generate_series thing is pretty advanced for me, and I'm not facile with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know Postgres, just TSQL, but you could try just declaring another CTE underneath the "daze" one inside the same WITH?

This page says it's possible in the Postgres syntax.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html

```
WITH daze 
     AS (SELECT ( CURRENT_DATE - b.offs ) AS date 
         FROM   (SELECT Generate_series(0, CURRENT_DATE - '2015-01-15', 1) AS 
                        offs) 
                AS b)
    ,foo
     as (select w.id, w.name, w.created_at 
         from waldo w, daze d
         where d.date + 1 > w.created_at)
select * from foo
```